# Programmatically Create Category and sub Category and sub sub Category

Tags: categories

I want insert category  like this:

> Category A
>
> - sub-category 1
>
>   - sub-sub-category 2
>
>     - sub-sub-category 3

thanks

this is my code

```
$term = wp_insert_term(
    $row[11], 
    'product_cat',
    [
        'description' => 'FooBar Category description', 
        'slug' => $row[11]
    ]
);
if(is_wp_error($term)) {
    $term_id = $term->error_data['term_exists'] ?? null;
} else {
    $term_id = $term['term_id'];
}
$term1 = wp_insert_term(
    $row[12], 
    'product_cat', 
    array(
        // what to use in the url for term archive
        'slug' => $row[12], 
        // link with main category. In the case, become a child of the "Category A" parent  
        'parent' => term_exists($row[11], 'product_cat')['term_id']
    )
);
$term2 = wp_insert_term($row[13], 'product_cat', 
    array(
        // what to use in the url for term archive
        'slug' => $row[13], 
        // link with main category. In the case, become a child of the "Category A" parent  
        'parent' => term_exists($row[12], 'product_cat')['term_id']
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you trying to insert child categories you are looking for **term_exists()** to return an array with a key **term_id**.

Following the documentation for [term_exists](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists)

Return Values

**(mixed)**

- Returns 0 or NULL if the term does not exist.
- Returns the term ID if no taxonomy was specified and the term exists.
- Returns an array if the parent exists. (format: array('term_id'=>term id, 'term_taxonomy_id'=>taxonomy id))

It seems that you are missing the third argument for **term_exists()** and this is the ID of the previously inserted category which will be parent.

Hope that helps!